# Python: Searching a file for a specific string and outputting the total string count

Tags: python, full-text-search

Attempting to build a search functionality in python that takes an input value/string from the user, searches an external file, and then returns the total count (sum) of that requested value in the file.

```
if user_search_method == 1:
with open("file.txt", 'r') as searchfile:
    for word in searchfile:
        word = word.lower()
        total = 0
        if user_search_value in word.split():
            total += word.count(user_search_value)
            print total
```

When I run this though I get a line-by-line count displayed and not a total sum.  When I add up those lines they are always 1 count short of the actual too.

Comment: you need your `print` statement at the same level of indent as the `for` statement. I'd normally expect a call to `readlines()` as well. Do you mean that the final count is one short, or the number of lines it has counted?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the `total` in each iteration, you have to put it out of `for` loop. Also you can do this job more pythonic, using one generator expression:

```
if user_search_method == 1:
    with open("file.txt") as searchfile:
        total = sum(line.lower().split().count(user_search_value) for line in searchfile)
    print total
```

Comment: Wouldn't breaking the generator - into more than one line - be clearer?

Comment: @boardrider No because its only one loop.

Comment: Given the apparent Python level of the OP, I'm not sure they can grasp the meaning of that complicated generator with ease. 
Seems that several lines in The Zen of Python support my assertion.

Comment: Kasramvd thank you for the response and suggestions.  I tested your inputs and while it is now printing out one simple sum of that total count as desired, that sum is not correct.  The string I am searching for appears a total of 56 times (mixed upper and lower case) in the file and when I run yours I am getting a sum of 19... weirdly enough I get that same total when running @e-ducateme 's suggested code below too.

Comment: I updated my original code a bit. If I move the 'print = total' statement outside the for loop, I get a sum of 0. If I keep it inside the for loop (as shown below) I get a count by line of text read (63 total lines) that have a sum of 56... the correct total, but not displayed as a simple sum. Any additional suggestions?
<code>
if user_search_method == 1:
    with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
        for word in searchfile.readlines():
     word = word.lower()
     total = word.count(user_search_value)
     print(total)
</code>

Comment: @RyanO'Shea Sorry I can't read your code, and even couldn't get the problem. I suggest you ask a new question, if you want to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like there might be something missing from your question, but I will try to get you to where it seems you want to go...

```
user_search_value = 'test'                     # adding this for completeness of 
                                               # this example
if user_search_method == 1:
    with open("file.txt", 'r') as searchfile:
        total = 0
        for word in searchfile:
            words = word.lower().split()       # breaking the words out, upfront, seems
                                               # more efficient

            if user_search_value in words:
                total += words.count(user_search_value)
        print total                            # the print total statement should be outside the for loop
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if user_search_method == 1:    
  total = 0    
  with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
      total += line.casefold().split().count(user_search_value.casefold())
  print(total)
```

This is probably what you wanted doing.